# How to configure or install GEARMAN in windows OS?

Tags: windows, gearman, python-gearman

I want to implement "GEARMAN" in project but I don't know how to install or configure "GEARMAN" in windows OS. Can anyone provide me any link from where I can work with "GEARMAN"?

Comment: It looks as though Gearman only runs on Linux at the moment.

Comment: Windows through the Perl Gearman server is somewhat supported, but really only for developing purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Gearman has to be compiled under the cygwin environment :
- install cygwin and open the shell;
- download and install libevent;
- download and install gearman server.

Here is a more detailed tutorial : http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/.

Comment: That link is dead/spam now :(

Answer (score 1):

Official website for "Gearman" is best I believe. 
You can find out "Documentation", "How to install" & "Examples" in this site :
http://gearman.org/

And also you will get examples here : 
http://php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-task.php

Getting Started with "Gearman" :
http://gearman.org/getting-started/

On Windows: http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

Best of luck. I believe you will love to work with "Gearman" with full gear.

Comment: please tell me how to install gearman on windows 7 with xampp. For OS link mentioned here is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How to install GEAR MAN

---

### References

1. http://www.cppblog.com/guojingjia2006/archive/2012/12/28/196743.html
2. https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256  ( Gearman and libevent folder downloaded and extracted from here )
3. https://julienliabeuf.com/installing-pear-windows/
4. http://www.smorgasbork.com/2010/06/16/building-a-distributed-app-with-netgearman-part-1/
5. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
6. https://github.com/brianlmoon/net_gearman   ( Net folder downloaded from here )
7. http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

## Steps

1. Download cygwin (setup-x86_64.exe)
2. Double click setup file
3. On select packages change view to -> Category
4. To install libuuid1-devel, Search for uuid   select the followings

   - Debug 1.221-2
   - Libs 2.25.2-2
   - Perl 1.221-2
5. To install libboost-devel, Search libboost-devel and select the followings

   - Libs 1.66.0-15.
6. To install libmpfr4, Search libmpfr4 and select the followings

   - Libs 3.1.6-1p1
   - Math 3.1.6-1p1
7. To install gcc-g++ , Search g++  and select the followings

   - Libs 7.3.0-2
8. Click next to install
9. Search on windows for cygwin-terminal -> click on it, This should be coming without any errors
10. Install more packages

    ### Goto CMD

    C:\cygwin64> setup-x86_64.exe -q -P make
    C:\cygwin64> setup-x86_64.exe -q -P boost
    C:\cygwin64> setup-x86_64.exe -q -P libiconv
11. Now cygwin installed successfully

11.1 Now download gearmand.*.* and libevent.*.*.* from (https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256) and paste into --> C:/cygwin64/tmp/

=================================================================================

12. Search on windows for cygwin-terminal -> click on it
13. type -> cd C:
14. Type --> cd cygwin64/tmp/libevent.*.*.*
15. Type -->    ./configure
16. Type --> make
17. Type --> make install

### Note:

Now libevent should be installed on /usr/local/lib, but this path is not in the library path and GCC will not find it automatically.

You can copy the generated libraries to /usr/lib:

cp /usr/local/lib/libevent* /usr/lib
(this is not the cleanest solution, you are welcome to propose an alternative)

---

### Now install gearman

18. If you are in /usr/lib right now, type /cygdrive/c to come to installation folder
19. Type --> cd tmp
20. Type --> cd cygwin64/tmp/gearman.*.*
21. Type -->    ./configure
22. Type --> make
23. Type --> make install

### Note:

************** Before this you need to enable port 4730 on windows firewall  Goto step 24 ******

Now the server is installed and you can launch it from a cygwin terminal:

/usr/local/sbin/gearmand.exe
Or if you want it to be ultra verbose:

/usr/local/sbin/gearmand.exe -vvv
You can also start the process and detach it from the terminal:

gearmand -d

=========================================================================

## Enabling port 4730 on inbound rules

24. control panel -> System and security -> windows firewall -> Advance settings -> inbound rules
25. right click inbound rules -> new rule -> Port -> Select Tcp -> Enter port number (4730)
26. click next -> Give name as "Gearman port"
27. Finish

==============================================================================

## Now we need to make gearman communicate with php PEAR

Reference --> this is for windows xampp ->  https://julienliabeuf.com/installing-pear-windows/

Following steps to install on windows iis server

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1
2. Enter --> system wide
3. Enter to continue
4. Proceed to change php.ini
5. Make sure php.ini -> include_path referst to pear path as follows

   ```
   ;***** Added by go-pear
       include_path=".;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\version.*\pear"
   ;*****
   ```
6. go to C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\version.*
7. Double click PEAR_ENV.reg  to add to environment variables
8. Copy Net folder and paste it inside -- C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\version.*\pear
9. On command prompt type -> pear install Net_Gearman-alpha
10. Enter
11. Open php.ini paste following line on end ( To enable socket )

    extension=php_sockets.dll

Note: Make sure php_sockets.dll exists under php/version.*/ext

11. Make copy of php.ini and rename it as php-cli.ini ( This is to run on command prompt )
12. Hooray! that's it, done.

Now you should try demo with following links
https://github.com/brianlmoon/net_gearman

Note: Don't forget to include libraries also

Comment: how much time it generally takes to complete step 8?

Comment: @Shwet For me I took a whole day, As i was not familiar with windows server.